# Get folder call returns OK even though folder is removed from BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have a folder created in BIM360 and its urn. When I delete the folder from BIM360, and when I call the get folder API, I expect it to return me 404, but it keeps returning 200 OK, even though folder doesn't exist anymore.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-GET/

Is above API call is the right call? If not which API can I use to get 404 response if the folder doesn't exist anymore?